# cucumber.io VS info.cukes , which group i should use for developing the cucumber framework

Tags: selenium, frameworks, cucumber, bdd

cucumber jars for selenium are given  by info.cukes and cucucumber.io , which one should i use. Any specific reason to use any of these

one difference i have observed is that when i have cucumber-java,cucumber-junit,cucumber-jvm,cucumber-jvm-deps, cucumber-reporting, cucumber-picocontainer jars from info.cukes, few features like inheritance ,dependency injunction are not working, when i have changed info.cukes to cucumber.io in pom.xml, the fatures are working. I am not sure if this is because of the info-cucks jars are not working or supported. Is these info.cukes groups is not suitable for cucumber project

Want to know which group jars i should use.

Comment: `info.cukes` is the old `groupId` for cucumber. They are still working on the library under `cucumber.io` `groupId` so this is the one to use. `info.cukes` is deprecated and might not work as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

info.cukes is deprecating slowly and it's not encouraged for further use. Most of the automation scripts written using info.cukes are migrated to io.cucumber
info.cukes was switched to io.cucumber to accompany changes in Gherkin jars which was consumed by Cucumber-JVM.
The info.cukes version of Gherkin is located in https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/gherkin and the io.cucumber version is at https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/gherkin

It is very important not to mix up the two groupIds in the same POM. It should be same for all the cucumber jar dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Cucumber directly you should use `io.cucumber`. You also should not concern yourself with any dependencies other then `cucumber-java`, `cucumber-junit` and `cucumber-picocontainer`. They'll be pulled in automatically by your dependency management tool. If you are not using a dependency management tool I would recommend using Maven, Gradle or if you are using Ant; Apache Ivy.

If you are using Cucumber through another project, you should use the groupId and version that project recommends.